# system running on low graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

When I booted my Ubuntu yesterday Its shows me a window saying "system running in low graphics mode"

After that I have searched on Google And tried almost everything. Like Sudo apt-get update

Installed and reinstalled Ubuntu desktop

And literally everything but nothing happened....

(I have installed gnome-desktop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error. Have you tried the suggestions at the following link? https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)